# Isn't 'y' in a diferential equation supposed to be a function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm now beginning to study differential equations at school and a question has popped into my head.

Let's take for example this differential equation:

> #### $$y' - 2y = 0$$

If our variable $y$ is a function shouldn't the equation be written like :

> #### $$y' - 2y(x)= 0  \quad ?$$

Comment: Indeed: writing
$$y'(x)-2y(x)=0$$
is perfectly correct.

Comment: The equation $y'-2y=0$ means that the derivative of the function $y$ minus twice the function $y$ is equal to the $0$ function. If you write $y'(x)-2y(x)=0$, to get the same differential equation you would need to write $\forall x,\ y'(x)-2y(x)=0$, where $0$ is this time the number $0$.

Comment: I would say that when one writes
$$
y' - 2y = 0
$$
they are assuming that the reader understand the omission of $(x)$. So in reality it means
$$
y'(x) - 2y(x) = 0
$$

Comment: $y$ is a function. In differential equations, it is customary often to omit the argument $(x)$ notation, as it's cumbersome and sometimes does not add value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, when you write something like $y'(x)-2y(x)=0$ you may mean one of many different things: either $x$ is some fixed value, or this holds for all $x$, or this holds for all $x$ from some domain which depends on the context.

Alternatively, we may agree that for any two functions $f$ and $g$ with identical domains we will write $f=g$ if $f$ and $g$ are identical as functions, i.e. have the same value at any point. Under this agreement, you would write $y'-2y=0$ to indicate that the function $y'-2y$ is identically zero. And this really simplifies notation later on.

Comment: Thank you @Serg for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Well you see there are two concepts

First is declaring a variable to a equation

$y=x^2$

Second is considering a machine f(x)

Where we input some value of x and it returns some value after performing some operations

These things have same meaning

What you are doing is absolutely fine but you have to write y' as y'(x)

By the way it is tradition to use y,z,t for algebraic equations whereas as f(x),g(x) are used in equations where you can cleary see what you are inputting. For example you do are just about to prove that you can make a wormhole using household things and you are are going to differentiate y in respect to t but you forget that what variables did y contain. There f(x) notation would be good because just after seeing the notation  you know what variables does it contain.(f(x,y,z) contains three variables x,y and z)